# What is this tiny creature?

Tags: species-identification

Is this a bed bug or book lice? They were crawling all around the furniture.[image]

Found in North East Florida, USA.

Comment: Is that a wooden surface? It could also be a termite. Do you have any additional pics?

Comment: Yes it was wooden surface. They were really tiny and fast. The other pictures are kind off blurry,

Comment: Book lice in Florida: https://inaturalist.ca/observations?place_id=21&subview=grid&taxon_id=372873
Bed Bugs in Florida: https://inaturalist.ca/observations?place_id=21&subview=grid&taxon_id=53667
Termites in Florida: https://inaturalist.ca/observations?place_id=21&subview=grid&taxon_id=118903&view=species
Ghost Ants in Florida: https://inaturalist.ca/observations?place_id=21&subview=grid&taxon_id=69122

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! For identification questions your post should include the size and location (e.g. country and region — the more specific the better) where you observed this creature. These can be essential clues for identifications. (Please [edit] this in since essential information should not be put into comments as they are ephemeral and often overlooked.) ——— If possible clear, closeup photos of the creature from multiple angles would also be helpful. ——— Please also take the [tour] and then go through the help pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site. Thanks! 

Answer (score 5):

The picture is hard to see details, but it seems you might be dealing with **ghost ants**:

[image]

I'm guessing ghost ants over lice or termites or bed bugs because their light-coloured abdomen ends off in a pointed end, rather than a round bulbous end. The darker thorax and antenna are also a match. And the distribution/range of ghost ants seems to be heavily concentrated in Florida:

[image]

(Map source:
https://inaturalist.ca/observations?nelat=39.32226574471&nelng=-51.18647084246517&place_id=any&swlat=18.339761895743152&swlng=-117.94819281111599&taxon_id=69122 )

Apparently, they smell like rotten coconuts when crushed. (http://entnemdept.ufl.edu/creatures/urban/ants/ghost_ant.htm )
They eat any kind of food, and they are easily controlled by eliminating food sources (so if they are in your furniture, maybe look within cushions or cracks for old dried food and clean it out).